# Export Data from MySQL to FTP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, ftp

I have a form that collects data from customers, i.e their names and emails etc. and then stores it in a database.  I want to be able to have this data from the database exported to an FTP and then later the data will be used to send out newsletters to the list of people that have filled out the form.

Once exported to the FTP the data is automatically added to a campaign I have set up, so I can manage who/what I send out, but I need a way of getting the data in from my database.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: Can you explain what part you're exactly requiring help with? Is this querying the database, determining the export format, writing a file, copying a file over FTP?

Comment: What you tried so far? What is your _specific_ problem? Provide valid code, describe what is not working and what is the expected result. From your question's title: `MySQL` is DBMS and `FTP` is network protocol - so how are they related?

Comment: [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)